# How to deploy j2ee application on apache http server?

Tags: apache, web, tomcat7

I want to deploy my j2ee application on apache http server. can anyone provide me a reference on how to set up and deploy j2ee application war in Apache http server?

is it possible to deploy war file to AHS?

Thanks,
Ezhil

Answer (score 1):

No, Apache doesn't have a Web Container.